# php if-statement: 0>2012?

Tags: php, if-statement, int

maybe a very simple question, however I have no idea what I do wrong, maybe someone could help me?

There is a GET-variable that contains the year and I want to check if it is actually a valid format and also not in the past, meaning the current year or later. What I did till now was:

```
$current_year=date('Y',$today);
```

`(is_int(intval($_GET['year'])) AND $_GET['year']>$current_year) ? $year=$_GET['year'] : $year=$current_year;`

The function intval() returns as it should 0 or 1 as stated in the php.net manual, if the GET-var is a not an integer, e.g. string "abc".

However, if $_GET['year'] contains "abc" which is then converted into 0 and should not be > 2012, $year is not 2012!?

Any hint would be highly appreciated and thank you in advance!

---

EDIT:

Thank you for all your great answers! I've tried to consider all of them, and this works now perfectly for me:

```
if (ctype_digit($_GET['year'])) { ($_GET['year'] > $current_year && $_GET['year']<=($current_year+2)) ? $year=$_GET['year'] : $year=$current_year;} else {$year=$current_year;}
```

As I only need the next 2 years in the future, I added this... thank you for the hint to check if it is only 4 digits, deceze! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intval` will mangle *anything* into an `int`, even if just into `0`, which means `is_int` is consequently always `true`. `is_int(intval())` is therefore pointless. `$_GET` values will always be strings, even if they only contain numbers. Therefore you probably want to check using [`ctype_digit`](http://www.php.net/ctype_digit), which tells you whether all characters in the string are numbers. So your check should look something like:

```
if (ctype_digit($_GET['year']) && $_GET['year'] > $current_year) ...
```

Comment: Is it not necessary to use  ctype_digit($_GET['year']) > $current_year

Comment: thank you a lot deceze!
@Sheikh Heera: why is it not necessary?

Comment: @Sheikh No. `ctype_digit` returns `true` or `false`. We're just checking whether the value is numeric and, if so, whether it's larger than the current year.

Comment: @Chris Since a year should have four digits (for the foreseeable future anyway) you may want to make the check even more strict with something like `preg_match('/^\d{4}$/', $_GET['year'])`.

Answer (score 1):

`intval()` does not change the type of the variable passed to it. So what you're *really* doing is comparing 'abc' to '2012', since `date()` returns a string.